# TypeScript / JS -- sort an array of nested objects based on a property common to all objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and JS and struggling to solve multiple problems. One of them is this, that I have at hand. Say, I have an array of Application objects. Each Application object has this kind of a nested structure:

Application
|
----[Document Type]
---------|
--------------[Document]
------------------|
------------------------Metadata

(Each `Application` has an array of `Document Type`.
Each `Document Typ`e has an array of `Document`.
Each `Document` has a `Metadata` inside it)

All the three objects types -- `Application`, `Document Type`, `Document`...have a property called `name` inside them.
I want to sort the entire array of `Application` objects (and recursively the nested objects as well), based on ascending order of the `name` property of each object. I had been trying multiple examples, but those are all sorting only the root level objects (`Application`) and not the nested objects.

Here is one such example I tried:

```
var simplePropertyRetriever = function(obj:any) {
      return obj.name;
     };

function sortArrayByName(propertyRetriever, arr:Application[]) {
   arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        var valueA = propertyRetriever(a);
        var valueB = propertyRetriever(b);

        if (valueA < valueB) {
            return -1;
        } else if (valueA > valueB) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });

  };
```

Can anybody please advise how to do this?
My sample JSON is this (I have arranged the objects in descending order here, to better explain my use case):

```
[
 {
  "name": "Application 2",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "Operations Manual",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-opsManual-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-opsManual-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "name": "Interface Contracts",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-IntContracts-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-IntContracts-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "name": "Application 2",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "User Manual",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-userManual-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-userManual-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "name": "System Design",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-SystemDesign-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-SystemDesign-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array and take the children for a new sorting.

```js
function sort(array) {
    array.forEach(({ children = [] }) => sort(children));
    array.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
}

var data = [{ name: "Application 2", children: [{ name: "Operations Manual", children: [{ name: "2nd-opsManual-app1", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "docx" } }, { name: "1st-opsManual-app1", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "pdf" } }] }, { name: "Interface Contracts", children: [{ name: "2nd-IntContracts-app1", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "docx" } }, { name: "1st-IntContracts-app1", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "pdf" } }] }] }, { name: "Application 2", children: [{ name: "User Manual", children: [{ name: "2nd-userManual-app2", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "docx" } }, { name: "1st-userManual-app2", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "pdf" } }] }, { name: "System Design", children: [{ name: "2nd-SystemDesign-app2", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "docx" } }, { name: "1st-SystemDesign-app2", metadata: { size: 56, fileExtension: "pdf" } }] }] }];

sort(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I'm going to use this snippet. Its so much more readable and concise. Is there a way this solution could be extended to take the  parameter name as an argument? (so that it can be used for any other parameter that's present in all the objects, just like `name`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, but you're only doing a shallow sort. If you need to also sort each application object's children, you can recursively call `sortArrayByName` on each application object's children (if they exist).

```js
var simplePropertyRetriever = function(obj) {
  return obj.name;
 };

function sortArrayByName(propertyRetriever, arr) {
 arr.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (Array.isArray(obj.children)) {
        sortArrayByName(propertyRetriever, obj.children);
      }
 });
 arr.sort(function (a, b) {
      var valueA = propertyRetriever(a);
      var valueB = propertyRetriever(b);

      if (valueA < valueB) {
          return -1;
      } else if (valueA > valueB) {
          return 1;
      } else {
          return 0;
      }
  });
};

const data = [
 {
  "name": "Application 2",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "Operations Manual",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-opsManual-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-opsManual-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "name": "Interface Contracts",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-IntContracts-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-IntContracts-app1",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "name": "Application 2",
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "User Manual",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-userManual-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-userManual-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "name": "System Design",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "2nd-SystemDesign-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "docx"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "1st-SystemDesign-app2",
      "metadata": {
       "size": 56,
       "fileExtension": "pdf"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
];

sortArrayByName(simplePropertyRetriever, data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was rather stupid of me to be not doing anything for recursion really..and expecting it work recursively.